# Javascript load() with data, how to grab params in PHP?

Tags: jquery

Ok so this is my following javascript code:

```
    $( '#listings' ).load( 'ajax/listingFind.php', {
        id: id, 
        name: name,
        logo: encodeURIComponent(logo),
        address: address,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        zip: zip,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        web_link: encodeURIComponent(web_link),
        distance: distance
      } );
```

All of the id, name, etc has values assigned previously in javascript.
However, in listingFind.php, how do I grab these data values that are being passed in?
I load the file into the div and echoed out the entire url and it doesn't seem as if the data is getting passed into the url.
Whenever I manually type it like so:

```
$( '#listings' ).load( 'ajax/listingFind.php?id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&logo=' + encodeURIComponent(logo) + '&address=' + address + 
          '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&zip=' + zip + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email + '&web_link=' + encodeURIComponent(web_link) + 
          '&distance=' + distance );
```

etc etc etc...
It throws an error saying :

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  Example
>   Inc&logo=http%3A%2F%2Fstuff.blah.localhost%2Flisting%2Flogo%2glarb.png&address=123
>   Any Street
>   N&city=Anytown&state=OH&zip=44123&phone=3305551234&email=foo@example.com&web_link=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&distance=16.85833142631359

Comment: You may want to genericize the data in your example error above, since it appears to be real data.

Comment: @Derek - Big time. OP - I've done it for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the data in [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). From the [`load` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> **Request Method**
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Since you're providing the data as an object, jQuery is using `POST`.

> Whenever I manually type it like so...It throws an error

Yes. If you provide a string, you're expected to provide a valid query string, but the string you provided is not a valid query string. In general, stick to the object notation, but if you *need* to build a string like that, use `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that the values are encoded correctly.

```
'ajax/listingFind.php?id=' + encodeURIComponennt(id)
```

Technically, both the key *and* value must be encoded:

```
'ajax/listingFind.php?' + encodeURIComponent('id') + '=' + encodeURIComponennt(id)
```

...but if your keys consist *solely* of the letters `a-z` (lower or upper case), the encoded form is exactly the same as the raw form, so you can skip it.